# Weird Javascript/jQuery if statement issue

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have a weird problem with a simple IF statement:

```
<script language='javascript' type="text/javascript">
    function laststep() {

        if(!document.touch.captcha.value == "L5J7K") {
            alert("Ingevoerde code is niet juist.");
            return false;
        }

        if(!document.touch.agree.checked) {
            alert("Accepteer algemene voorwaarden.");
            return false;           
        }
    }
</script>
```

The second IF condition is working correctly. But the first one isn't working. The value of the first one is 'NotProvided'.

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Could you add you markup code, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(!document.touch.captcha.value == "L5J7K"){
```

Should be

```
if(!(document.touch.captcha.value == "L5J7K")){
```

Or

```
if(document.touch.captcha.value != "L5J7K"){
```

In your current code, `!document.touch.captcha.value` is evaluated first, and that result is then compared to `"L5J7K"`, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`!document...` will cast it to a boolean for comparison where it will be false and the statement will never succeed because the string is truthy.

```
if (document.touch.captcha.value != "L5J7K"){
```

Comment: `will cast it to a boolean for comparison where it will be false and the statement will never succeed because the string is truthy` ...well, unless the string is empty :)

Comment: @Ian I was referring to the specific string in the question, but you are correct.  An alternative would be to use `!===`

Comment: I know, I was just giving you a hard time :)